# How do I show a taskbar notification in my C# application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show a taskbar notification in my application. How can i achieve this in C#?

Comment: 13 questions, not a single answer marked...

Comment: @Amit: What J. Steen is saying is that you'll get better responses on Stack Overflow if you Accept answers on your questions.  That means choosing the answer that you found to be the most helpful, and clicking the green checkmark at the left-hand side of that answer.  It's considered polite to accept answers, and people will be discouraged from answering your questions if you don't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a good implementation of one of these here on CodeProject: [TaskbarNotifier, a skinnable MSN Messenger-like popup](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use **[NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx)**

Also check community response in comments for notable issues of using NotifyIcon.

Comment: Is your link broken?  It goes to a page about exception handling.