# chat message alert like Gmail Alert

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a beginner with WPF.I create chat application. Now I have problem with message alert. So,I want to create message alert. For Example: When other user A chat to user B.User B will see the alert message on taskbar after that,if User B wants to reply, User B must click on taskbar to show Form Chat.

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=wpf+chat+application. 
Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

[use notificationwindow library use this link for more study](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.notificationwindow%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

this is similar post of [How do I show a taskbar notification in my C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476086/how-do-i-show-a-taskbar-notification-in-my-c-sharp-application)